# How to define the min-width of an element that only affects it if its content is longer than the min-width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a list of items that contain two `<span>` elements with text. **The text will be generated with JavaScript and can vary in length.**

Both elements should fill the whole box (which altogether is in a container with fixed width) if the text is long enough, but align themselves to the left if their total length is shorter than the `<div>` around them. I used `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to hide overflowing text. Apparently if the text is very long in one `<span>` and very short in the other `<span>` the longer one gets more space. I tried to set a `min-width` to prevent the shorter element from being too short but this results in creating a space when the text is shorter than the `min-width`

Here is the basic Structure of the HTML with a dummy `<div class="item">` which will be generated by JavaScript

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="issue">foooooo</span>
    <span class="project">foooooo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  background-color: silver;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item span {
  /* min-width: 8ch;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.project {
  color: teal;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

---

Here is a live example:
**[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/freezech/pen/qBMBYeg)**

---

I tried to find a way to get this done with `min-width` and also tried `flex-basis` or `flex`, but my approaches weren't successful. I'm not sure if the way I approach this is going in the right direction anyway.

**Is there a CSS or CSS+HTML solution that defines a `min-width` of let's say `8ch` that only affects the element if its content is longer than the `min-width`?** Is there some CSS way to create a flexible min-width situation?

Comment: in other words, you want min-width to apply only if there is overflow of both content?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes. And it should only affect a `<span>` itself, if it is longer than the min-width.